# Not able to connect ibm_db to Python on Jupyter not working

Tags: python, db2, ibm-cloud, jupyter

I have created an instance of the db2 database on the cloud in IBM, and I get the following error.

> {"trace":"1ef30d2fa8c730e79ef03f4da34f175c","errors":[{"code":"authentication_failure","message":"HWCSEC0005E:
> Check role failed,Unauthorized Access! Authentication pass but the
> login user is configured neither as administrator nor user
> role.","target":{"type":"","name":""},"more_info":""}]}

and then I try to connect Python to the ibm_db2 database and get the following error message in my Jupyter notebook:

Comment: How is the user configured, how did you authenticate? There is an IAM user mapping to administrator and regular user roles.

Comment: thank you @data_henrik for the help! I'm quite new to all this.. which tab would I click to give myself authentication to the console. Because I went to the 'Manage' tab and clicked on Access (IAM) and not sure where to go from here? And it's also quite odd that it hasn't been working for me recently as it worked very well when i initially signed up!

Comment: There are several tabs under the IAM tab but not sure which one to go to? I've tried to create a 'role' for myself and added all the services that relate to the console, but that didn't help either:                                                               
Users
, Access groups
,Roles
,Service IDs
,Authorizations
,Identity providers
,API keys
,Settings

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting#Code%20Blocks and use `\`\`\`` code fences, copy/paste your output error into code fences. Image links are discouraged.

Comment: please, if anyone can help me, i would be very grateful!

Comment: please edit your question. The image shows 2 symptoms , both are different from the text error HWCSEC0005E. So which error do you want help with?  Use one question, for one symptom.   Do not show your credentials in the image.  jupyter notebook works fine for me with Db2-on-cloud. You just have to use it correctly.